# SAP Spartacus - single Spartacus application for multiple web stores

Tags: spartacus-storefront

How to set up a **single Spartacus application** to run **several different web stores** against a single BA Hybris (several Base Stores).

We need to ensure that the user sessions are **not mixing**.

What would be the configuration for the Spartacus and what are the eventual implications.

What should be done on the BA side.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Spartacus can automatically detect existing sites with requesting below URL: `https://backend.site/occ/v2/basesites?fields=baseSites(uid,defaultLanguage(isocode),urlEncodingAttributes,urlPatterns,stores(currencies(isocode),defaultCurrency(isocode),languages(isocode),defaultLanguage(isocode)),theme,defaultPreviewCatalogId,defaultPreviewCategoryCode,defaultPreviewProductCode)&lang=en&curr=USD`
Spartacus will match current URL with existing website URLs on backaoffice. Check [spartacus documentation](https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/automatic-context-configuration/) for details.

You need custom implementation for prevent mixing user sessions. Because spartacus using OAuth2 protocol. You can use UserFilter or others for checking it.

You didn't share your customization so I can't say about your BE works.

If you haven't got any customization, you just need to implement filter for checking user tokens for preventing mixing sites in BE side.

Comment: Also refer to the Spartacus documentation for implementation details of automatic multi-site configuration:
https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/automatic-context-configuration/